# Are MAPCAR, MAPC, and MAP compiled to similar code when result is ignored?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

First question: Is it reasonable to assume that a modern compiler for Common Lisp will usually compile `(mapcar #'fn ...)` and `(map 'list #'fn ...)` into the same code as `(mapc #'fn ...)`? That is, is it reasonable to assume that a compiler will see that the return value is ignored, so that a new list doesn't need to be constructed?  e.g. suppose that my source file contains this code:

```
(defun set-foo-5 (sym)
  (setf (get sym 'foo) 5))

(progn 
  (mapcar #'set-foo-5 '(a b c))
  (format t "All foos are five!~%"))
```

Would `mapc` be more efficient?  I usually run SBCL, but my guess is that any good compiler would be able to figure out that there's no need to cons up a new list in this situation.  Am I right?

Second question: In the same situation, should I assume that a modern compiler will usually compile `map 'list` into the same code as `mapcar`, as long as `'list` is there in the source code, and not chosen at run time?

Third question: Similar question for other sequences.  For example, if I replace the `mapcar` line in the progn above with `(map 'vector #'set-foo-5 #(a b c))`, should I assume that that the compiled code will not bother to construct a new vector?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First** of all, [`map`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm) and [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) differ in a very important way: the latter operates on [**lists**](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_list.htm) while the former works with any [**sequences**](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_seq.htm).  This means that `(map nil ...)` (or `(map 'list ...)`) is equivalent to `(mapc ...)` (resp. `(mapcar ...)`) only if the compiler can *prove* that all the data arguments are `list`s.

**Second**, most modern Lisp compilers (e.g., [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/)) are usually good enough to figure out such things (with declarations, when necessary).

**Third**, the only way to be sure is to use [`disassemble`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_disass.htm).

**Fourth**, the function choice is a way to *document your code*. When you use `map`, you are telling the human reader of your code that you will be passing non-lists to the function. If you are sure that only lists will be used, why would you want to confuse the reader (yourself a few months later)?

**Fifth**, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/72677).

Comment: Thanks sds!  I didn't know about `(map nil ...)`.  I agree about signalling to human reader--that's why I like `mapc`.  I want to use `map`, along with other sequence functions, so that by changing a few global parameters and constants, I can test the effect on speed of lists vs vectors passed around in a moderately large program.  Didn't want unexpected gc to get in the way.  But I didn't think about the fact that the compiler would have to prove what sequence types are used.  That may require additional changes for the two sequence types, i.e. declarations.

Comment: yes, done.  I sometimes wait a few days to do that.  It appears that recent compilers are not as good about translating e.g. `mapcar` to `mapc` as I'd hoped, but your answer was exactly what I was looking for, and played a role in getting me to see how I could do further investigation on my own.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using some of the tips in @sds's answer, I realized that there are simple preliminary tests that might answer my question for a specific implementation (without having to work through `dissemble` output).  It appears that SBCL and CCL do not necessarily treat `mapcar` the same way as `mapc` when `mapcar`'s return value is ignored.  First define `lis1` and `lis2` as lists of significant length (mine were length 100,000, and contained integers), then run `mapcar`, `mapc`, etc. over them many times, as in the the following (with optional preliminary calls to `gc` to clear out old garbage):

```
(gc :full t)
(time 
  (progn
    (dotimes (ignored 1000)
      (mapcar #'+ lis1 lis2))
    (format t "mapcar:~%")))

(gc :full t)
(time 
  (progn
    (dotimes (ignored 1000)
      (mapc #'+ lis1 lis2))
    (format t "mapc:~%")))

(gc :full t)
(time 
  (progn
    (dotimes (ignored 1000)
      (map nil #'+ (the list lis1) (the list lis2)))
    (format t "map nil with lists~%")))
```

For example, SBCL on my machine produces:

```
mapcar:
Evaluation took:
  2.306 seconds of real time
  2.287627 seconds of total run time (2.136130 user, 0.151497 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.147 seconds GC time, and 2.141 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.22% CPU
  3,683,188,504 processor cycles
  1,600,049,536 bytes consed

mapc:
Evaluation took:
  0.639 seconds of real time
  0.638733 seconds of total run time (0.638011 user, 0.000722 system)
  100.00% CPU
  1,020,310,296 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed

map nil with lists
Evaluation took:
  0.592 seconds of real time
  0.592114 seconds of total run time (0.591199 user, 0.000915 system)
  100.00% CPU
  945,957,944 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

These are typical results with default optimization settings.  Using `declaim` to optimize for speed, non-safety, etc. speeds things up a little bit but doesn't change the fact that `mapc` and `map nil` are an order of magnitude faster than `mapcar`, and that `mapcar` does a lot of consing.  Results for CCL are similar, but slower overall.

Comment: Huzzah for actually measuring, to answer questions regarding performance of various available solutions.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I didn't see how easy it was.  Now I'm going crazy running speed tests on all of the basic operations my main application does often, figuring out, for example, when there's no reason to replace lists with arrays, for example.  (Example: When all I want to do map a function over a sequence of symbols, `mapc` on a list appears to be as fast as `map nil` on an array in SBCL.)